# Windows Service Issue in C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have designed a window service in which I called RunProgram Method from OnStart().. But when I install its pakage it is not showing in service console.... Any suggestions are most welcome....

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            rd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunProgram));
            rd.Start();
        }
```

my Installer class is as follows....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Management;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Linq;


namespace WindowsService1
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController();
        private void ProjectInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            serviceController.ServiceName = "MyTestingService";
            ConnectionOptions coOptions = new ConnectionOptions();


            coOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

            ManagementScope mgmtScope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"root\CIMV2", coOptions);

            mgmtScope.Connect();

            ManagementObject wmiService;

            wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + this.serviceController.ServiceName + "'");

            ManagementBaseObject InParam = wmiService.GetMethodParameters("Change");

            InParam["DesktopInteract"] = true;

            ManagementBaseObject OutParam = wmiService.InvokeMethod("Change", InParam, null);

            this.serviceController.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

My Service Class is as follows....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class MyTestingService : ServiceBase
    {
        public MyTestingService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread rd;
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            rd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunProgram));
            rd.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }
        public void RunProgram()
        {


           //My Code to do here


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What 'service console' are you referring to? How are you installing the service?

Comment: is it possible to post the code for the entire service class?

Comment: Please share the installer class you used (if any) for this, I'm assuming service console => services.msc on windows? is that right? Edit your question to provide these details.

Comment: Hi I have added my Installer class ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you any logging file? Maybe there is some error in your webservice. You can debug your webservice too.

```
static void Main()
{
#if (!DEBUG)


            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Service1Component() };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);


#else
            Service1Component s = new Service1Component();
            s.RunProgram();
#endif
}
```

P.s. `s.RunProgram()` is your method that you can use it for debug.

Comment: Service code is OK ..  I have checked by debugging each line but problem is in deploying process my service is not listing in service console. Please help...

Comment: @Ramiro Berrelleza answer did not solve your problem? For service installment 
open **cmd**
write this path: **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727** 
execute this command line **InstallUtil.exe c:\yourprojectdirectory\bin\Debug\service.exe**

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx
I remember that in old services prior to .NET you shoud also register the service installing it
The installer had a specific key, smth like "autoregister"

Comment: I have cheched each and every step... but my service is not listing in service console.... what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your service built, you have to run the following command from a Visual Studio Command Propt:

```
installutil [/u[ninstall]] [options] assembly [[options] assembly] ...
```

Full info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check whether you have done the following steps:

1.After creating the windows service project go to the service class's design view(just double click the service1.cs class).

2.In the design view right click and select **Add Installer**. This will create an Installer class named **ProjectInstaller.cs**. With out ProjectInstaller.cs or any error in configuring ProjectInstaller.cs may result in non-showing of the service in service console.

3.Go to the design view of **ProjectInstaller.cs** you will find two installers there->

```
a.**ServiceInstaller1**

b.**ServiceProcessInstaller1**
```

4.Right click **ServiceInstaller1** and go to the properties tab

```
a.Edit the ServiceName with the name you want to 
   see your service in the service console.

   b.Change the **StartType** to **Automatic**.
```

5.Right click **ServiceProcessInstaller1** and go to the properties tab

```
 a.Change the account to **LocalService**

6. Save and try it.
```

Hope this will help you........